# RShiny error: comparison (3) is possible only for atomic and list types

Tags: r, shiny

I am building an RShiny application. I have read through some other threads here on stackoverflow with similar issues and now I sort of feel what the problem is (I call a function and want to compare it to a scalar) but unfortunately, it doesn't help me to move forward with my issue.

Below you see a simplified code to show you what I am trying to achieve. Basically I want to take the `discount_fn` function's substitution value for various `x` values and do different tasks depending on the condition. For simplicity, I changed these to fix numbers.

Additionally, another weird thing is that the moment I comment out the entire if condition section, my error message changes to argument 1 (type 'closure') cannot be handled by 'cat'.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  textOutput("results"),
  hr(),
  fluidRow(
    column(3, 
           numericInput("price", "price:", 50, min = 0, max = 99999, step = 1),
           numericInput("day_price", "day price:", 0.05, min = 0, max = 1, step = 0.001),
           sliderInput("aggregated_cost", "aggregated cost", "min" = 0, "value" = 25, "max" = 100, "step" = 1)
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  price        <- reactive({ input$price })
  day_price    <- reactive({ input$day_price })
  AC           <- reactive({ input$aggregated_cost })
  discount_fn  <- function(x){ 1-(day_price()/price() )*x }

  output$results <- renderText({
    if(discount_fn(5) < AC ) {
       # do something
    }
    else if(discount_fn(5) >= AC & discount_fn(5) < AC*1.5 ) {
       # do something different
    }   
    else {
       # do again something different
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example which includes ui and server function calls.

Comment: Where are you running these `if` statements? Is it side a reactive environment? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Sorry, I updated it.

Comment: When you create reactive expressions in shiny (i.e., `reactive({ })`), you refer to them elsewhere like you would a function. This means you need to use parentheses. Specifically, use `AC()` instead of `AC` in your if statements.

Comment: Pretty much a duplicate of this (with different error message). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48239366/object-of-type-closure-is-not-subsettable-in-r-shiny. When using reactive objects, you need to get their value with the parenthesis call syntax as pointed out above.

Comment: Oh gosh, that's so much of a shame. You see, in other instances, I could use it properly with the brackets... lack of attention from my side. Thank you very much for your help!